# How to use firebase in 2 different projects?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I'm working on an application where I'm using Android and Flutter, more specifically I have a login created in Android where I pass to the main that I have in Flutter.

The project that I have on Android is connected to Firebase to perform user authentication.

Is it possible that I can use that same database for my project in Flutter? Would I have to add it as another Android application or do it from Ios?

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter project can also use the same database as the Android project, just navigate to the Firebase console -> Project Overview and click on add app then follow the setup in the following link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#configure_an_android_app

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#configure_an_ios_app